# What is the difference between replace a node and remove/add a new one?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

Is there any difference between replacing a node in the cluster and removing/adding a new node?

I think, removing a node and then add a new one will work fine like replacing without the following argument.

```
–Dcassandra.replace_address=[old_address]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you remove the node using `nodetool removenode`, the data that it handles are distributed to other nodes, and when you add a new node then the data is streamed back, so all data is moved 2 times.

By using `-Dcassandra.replace_address=[old_address]` you avoid streaming data from node that is removed, so streaming happens only once.

P.S. corresponding part of [DSE documentation](http://docsreview.datastax.lan/en/dse/5.1/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/operations/opsReplaceLiveNodeAlternate.html).